# get the most selling product

Tags: mysql, sql

well, I want to get the best selling product, but when I want to get them. it just return the best selling product, but not idventa,idproduct,and description. well return the values but they are wrong values which they belong to other one. I need someone help me to correct me statement on sql because I want to return the right values like: idventa: 7 - idproducto: 10 , descripcion: IPHONE 4S, best_selling_product: 5000, and not the other values which they are not belong to the sentence

```
SELECT
   idventa,idproducto,descripcion,MAX(venta_detalle.cantidad) AS best_selling_product 
FROM venta_detalle 
     INNER JOIN producto 
     ON venta_detalle.idproducto = producto.id
```

Comment: Guessing a bit, but are you missing `group by idventa`?  Sample data and expected results would make this easier to understand.  `Mysql` allows this behavior but doesn't guarantee the correct result (which it shouldn't imo)...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structures, it's a little difficult to guess what you're looking for.  Sometimes you can get away with adding a `group by` clause assuming `distinct` values exist for that field.

Other times you need to `join` the table back to itself using aggregation in a subquery:

```
select
   p.idproducto, 
   p.descripcion,
   vd.idventa, 
   vd.cantidad
from producto p 
   join venta_detalle vd on vd.idproducto = p.id
   join (select idproducto, max(cantidad) best_selling_product 
         from venta_detalle
         group by idproducto) vd2 on vd.idproducto = vd2.idproducto and
                                    vd.cantidad = vd2.best_selling_product
```

Comment: @AronImperial -- this is why sample data and expected results would help understand what you're trying to do.  I was taking a bit of a guess to be honest.  If you only want a single result,  no reason for `group by` -- just use `order by` with `limit` as in the other posted solution.

Comment: @AronImperial this is a different question, you should ask it it in its own separate post!

Answer (score 0):

Although max() will return the highest number and without a group by it will also collapse the resultset into a single record, however, there is no guarantee that the other fields will come from the same record as the max. I suggest a simple order by and limit combo to get the record with the highest value:

```
SELECT
   idventa,idproducto,descripcion, venta_detalle.cantidad AS best_selling_product 
FROM venta_detalle 
     INNER JOIN producto 
     ON venta_detalle.idproducto = producto.id
ORDER BY venta_detalle.cantidad DESC
LIMIT 1
```